# JENKINS - Overriding specific target in config.xml

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 5 Jenkins servers (for projects) + 1 (for administration) with common a config.xml.

But for each server I want to have specific Dashboard view. These views are defined in the config.xml (tag : hudson.plugins.view.dashboard.Dashboard)

is there a way to have a specific configuration files and import it in the common config.xml (like a import resource="./config-specific.xml) ? (I try it= > don't work))

I can't have a specific config.xml by server, it must be common for each server.

Thanks

Comment: [XIncludes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XInclude) could be a solution to that. The only point is that you must enable the XInclude feature for the XML parser that's used by Jenkins (by default, it's disabled). If you're willing to modify `core/src/main/java/hudson/XmlFile.java`, then adding a `JAXP.setXIncludeAware(true)` should do the trick. I didn't figure out yet if it's possible to do the same dynamically by setting a static system property like `-D...=true`. Also, XIncludes may be lost when Jenkins updates the config files itself.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and see

Comment: @AlexO Could you post it as an answer, please?

Comment: sure -- did it work for you?

Comment: I will try it today and give you an answer. But I need some authorization at work before

Answer (score 0):

[XIncludes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XInclude) could be a solution to that.

The only point is that you must enable the XInclude feature for the XML parser that's used by Jenkins (by default, it's disabled). If you're willing to modify `core/src/main/java/hudson/XmlFile.java`, then adding a `JAXP.setXIncludeAware(true)` should do the trick.

I didn't figure out yet if it's possible to do the same dynamically by setting a static system property like `-D...=true`. Also, XIncludes may be lost when Jenkins updates the config files itself.